# Mass auto layout option for 40 viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I designed about 40 view controllers using a 5.5 inch storyboard layout. After all of that I tested it on the iPhone 4S...big mistake. everything is jumbled together being for a larger screen size. I was able to fix one view controller up using Size Classes. I am wondering if there is any way I can adjust all 40 at the same time, or at least avoid doing this for every single one. It is really frustrating finding this out now. Thanks!

Comment: What is 5.5 inch storyboard layout? What size class are you using?

Comment: How similar are these 40 view controllers (and why the heck do you need 40)? Unless a bunch of them are identical, there's no way to do it other than one by one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a relatively complicated issue you are attempting to solve, but I have two potential solutions. Both suggestions are based on moving your current interface into containing `UIScrollView` instances

1. If you are using storyboards, then for each of your view controller scenes, put a `UIScrollView` as a descendent of the view controller's view. From there, provided your subviews are contained within other views (like a container view for a set of buttons), you can move those into your scroll view. You will have to setup constraints to define the size of the scroll view's content, but this will allow the size of the device to have a smaller impact on the interface as you will get scrolling as needed.
2. If you are using nib files (`.xib`) then it is essentially the same thing, but easier. In this case, move a `UIScrollView` onto the canvas, but not as a subview of the default view. Once that is out there, move the original view to be a subview of the scroll view and set constraints to be `0` from the subview to the scroll view. Finally, right click drag from the `File's Owner` icon to the scroll view and set that as the `view` outlet.

Hopefully one of these will help you.